# String formatting

Tags: c#

I made timer, which outputs time like this:

```
0:1, 0:2, 0:3 ... 0:10 ...
string.Format("{0}:{1}", hours, minutes);
```

But I want to output as follows:

```
00:01, 00:02, 00:03
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
0:1, 0:2, 0:3 ... 0:10 ...
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", hours, minutes);
```

Will output

```
00:01, 00:02, 00:03
```

Answer (score 2):

How about reading the .NET documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx ?
Many working samples already provided by others...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `DateTime` object, you can say:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
// string.Format("{0:hh:mm}", dt);
```

If you have numbers, use:

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", hours, minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("{0,2}:{1,2}", hours, minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# to have leading Zero you can use Format :

```
intValue.ToString("00.##");
```

So, if you want to have your minute and second with leading zero you can use:

```
string.Format("{0}:{1}", hours.ToString("00.##"), minutes.ToString("00.##"));
```

If your timer use the TimeSpan object you can use the Format for the TimeSpan:

```
myTimeSpan.Format("hh:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should take a [look at this site](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/). it gives a nice run-down on string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the toString on the Timespan or datetime object or you could change you code to the following

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}");
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if there is a simple and correct way of doing it.. but anyway you can write this

```
  String.Format("{0}:{1}",hours < 10 ? ("0" + hours) : hours,  minutes < 10 ? ("0" + minutes) : minutes);
```

hopes it's help...  :)